# SEP-24 deposit failed The transaction source account is not equal to the server's account

Tags: transactions, assets, payments

I'm working through the steps of setting up the Stellar Anchor platform. Docker is all set up and working okay. I'm at the stage where I test the Stellar Demo wallet by Initiating a SEP-24 deposit. I get the following error message --> SEP-24 deposit failed The transaction source account is not equal to the server's account.

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by a rookie mistake, I had entered my JWT key as the value for “SIGNING_KEY” in my stellar.toml file instead of entering the public key of my distribution account.